# How do I write a URL so that it's launched in an app instead of the browser

Tags: ios, google-calendar-api

I have this Pushover message that's supposed to include a Google Calendar app link but the link is always opened in the browser instead of the app.

`https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0?cid=YXJzNGw0bjEyM0BnbWFpbC5jb20`

I read in a vague user post that I need to replace the https with the apps' package name but I have no idea where to even find that.
I took a guess and tried:
`google calendar://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0?cid=YXJzNGw0bjEyM0BnbWFpbC5jb20` and
`google_calendar://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0?cid=YXJzNGw0bjEyM0BnbWFpbC5jb20`
but those links weren't openable

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

To create a link to open the Google Calendar app and view an event you'll need to follow a specific format called a Universal Link (, on iOS) or App Link (on Android). While Google Calendar doesn't officially support linking to an event through a URL there are alternative methods you can use to achieve this.

One approach is to utilize the Google Calendar API for creating an event and then launching the Google Calendar app with that event. This requires utilizing the Google Calendar API.

If your intention is simply to open the Google Calendar app with an URL it's important to note that this isn't officially supported. The behavior may vary depending on your device and settings. It's possible that Google Calendar has its way of handling links or may not support them at all.

Regarding Android linking while you can typically find package names in an apps file they aren't usually intended for deep linking into specific events or content within an app.

If deep linking is crucial, for your application it might be beneficial to reach out to Google Calendars development or support team for guidance. They may provide recommendations or APIs that can assist you in achieving your desired outcome.
It's important to note that directly linking to events, within third party apps might not always be a task. The feasibility of this depends on the apps functionalities. Whether the developers have incorporated support, for features.

Comment: hi, ty for the answer. Can you demonstrate how to do one of those universal links? API docs and such are usually too complicated for me. I'm just a guy who sometimes deals with code as a hobby

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're looking for a simple solution to create a deep link to open Google Calendar with a specific event, and you'd prefer not to dive into the complexities of APIs. Unfortunately, Google Calendar does not provide a simple public URL scheme or universal link that allows you to open the app directly to a specific event, especially without using an API.

The handling of deep links and universal links is specific to the app itself, and Google Calendar doesn't publicly document such a scheme for direct event linking.

If you're looking for a straightforward solution and don't want to use APIs, here's an alternative approach.

**Create an Event Reminder Web Page**

Create a web page on your website that contains event details and provides a "Add to Google Calendar" button. You can use the Google Calendar API or a service like "addtocalendar.com" to generate a link that, when clicked, allows users to add the event to their Google Calendar. This way, users can click the link from their device, and the Google Calendar app will handle the event addition.

Here's a simple example of how you can use "addtocalendar.com"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Event Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Event Title</h1>
    <p>Event Description</p>
    <p>Date and Time: [Event Date and Time]</p>

    <!-- Generate the "Add to Google Calendar" link using addtocalendar.com -->
    <a href="https://addtocalendar.com/atc/google?v=1&url=https://yourwebsite.com/event-details&title=Event%20Title&description=Event%20Description&date=Event%20Date%20and%20Time&st=Event%20Start%20Time&et=Event%20End%20Time" class="addeventatc">Add to Calendar</a>

    <script type="text/javascript" src "https://addtocalendar.com/atc/1.5/atc.min.js" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```